# how set subfigure 4 rows and 8 cols and a line in middle as figure shows

Tags: subfloats

How I finish this effect in my paper, 4 rows figures and 8 eights figures, especially a red line is in middle of the whole figure. Please. Can you help me finish?
[image]

Comment: Can you show the work you've got so far? It will help us a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible solution where `matrix of node` from tikzlibrary matrix is used and defined with a name called table.

[width=xx and height=xx] in the includegraphics options are for the size of images.

row sep=xx and col sep=xx are for the row and column separation.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lscape,amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{0.5}
\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,  % <-- This adjusts the row separation
  column sep=\pgflinewidth,% <-- This adjusts the column separation
  nodes={rectangle,draw=none, text width=2cm, align=center,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt},
%  nodes in empty cells
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (mat) [table]
{
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A} & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A} & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A} & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A} & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}  
& \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B} &  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B} &  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}\\
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A} & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}  &\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}&\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}  &\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}  & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B} &  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}&  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}\\
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A} & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}  &\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}&\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-A}  &\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}  & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B} &  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}&  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-B}\\
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.3cm]{example-image-A} & \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.3cm]{example-image-A}  &\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.3cm]{example-image-A}&\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.3cm]{example-image-A}  &\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.3cm]{example-image-B}& \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.3cm]{example-image-B} &  \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.3cm]{example-image-B} &  \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.3cm]{example-image-B}\\
};
\draw[red,dashed,very thick](mat-1-4.north east)--(mat-4-4.south east);  %<-- This is for the red line in the middle
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It runs OK, but I write my paper, it does not work well, it shows "LaTeX Error: Command \@EveryShipout@Hook already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.". Can you give me your e-mail? I want to further ask some questions. Thanka a lot

Comment: Actually, you can ask another question with your minimum (non) working example (this means, minimizing your paper to the minimum code that shows the errors. The users here will provide you the some directions.